# Howto convert excel formula to work in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I have found this terrific tip:

http://vlookupweek.wordpress.com/2012/03/27/richard-schollar-vlookup-left

However, the formula

```
=VLOOKUP(F2,CHOOSE({1,2},$C$2:$C$7,$A$2:$A$7),2,False)
```

works if entered in a cell but in VBA it gives a syntax error:

```
Set Rng = Range(Application.WorksheetFunction.Choose({1, 2}, colMax.Address, colId.Address))
```

Since this works althought it doesn't do what I want:

```
Set Rng = Range(Application.WorksheetFunction.Choose(1, colMax.Address, colId.Address))
```

it seems to be the {...} that is the problem. The problem with googling this is that I don't know what {...} is called (array, sequence list...???).

So the question is how to use this tip in VBA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the Evaluate function to evalute the formula in VBA. There is no need of "translating" it to VBA:

See this link
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193019(v=office.15).aspx